# Use of __construct or setVar()

Tags: php, oop, constructor

I've started using OOP with PHP and constructed my variables in a way like this:

```
public $var;
public function setVar($var) {
    $this->var = $var;
}
```

Now i came across the magic function of __construct. If I understand this correctly you can use this function to achieve the same in a manner like this:

```
public $var;
public function __construct($var) {
$this->$var = $var;
}
```

My question is the following: Is there a difference between these two methods? Which one is considered more clean and why?
Also are there any pitfalls with my first method I'm not aware of?

Comment: Related: https://williamdurand.fr/2013/06/03/object-calisthenics/#9-no-getterssettersproperties

Comment: If you have all values when creating object - use constructor, otherwise you only left with setters/direct modification

Comment: Constructor should be used to initialise anything you care about having an initial value.

Getters/Setters are also good practice, as allows you to set/retrieve values and not care about their implementation, i.e. you have the flexibility to rename things inside you're class as it evolves while something external to that class can use a getter and not care about this.